# Kali Linux - Help after having interrupted apt-get upgrade

Tags: terminal, boot, apt, kali-linux, crash

Yesterday I was using kali linux 2 and I was trying to update using `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` like usual. After quite some time (I'm in a hospital with crappy wifi and it's been almost a month since I booted from my persistent kali usb so I had lots of updates to do) I had to shutdown my laptop. So, I pressed ctrl+c to 'pause' updating (I thought that if you did that kali would simply suspend everything with no problems). Today I tried booting and it gives me strange errors.
When I select the persistence option the normal black and white screen kicks-in.

It says `wlan0: link not ready.` or something like that after a while. After some time it boots but the background is black and icons are invisible. If I open something, it crashes, if I wait more time without doing anything, it still crashes.

After crashing it resumes to the black screen with the normal text and the same `wlan0: link not ready.` and it lets me type, but nothing happens! Since it seems it's a problem with wlan0 I tried typing `ifconfig wlan0 up`. But still, nothing! How can I solve this? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Reinstall the packages? How? What do you mean? Can you explain please? @Fox

Answer (score 1):

Since [Kali isn't meant to be your everyday desktop Linux](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) and you said you are using persistence it should be sufficient to move the data in the persistence some where else and start from scratch with a new persistence overlay.

Usually it's expected of a Kali Linux user be able to post the relevant apt log hinting the problem instead of just the symptom.

Comment: Yeah I'll probably do that